# Human readable price in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for function to echo price like this:

```
17.0 #=> 17
17.5 #=> 17.50
```

`number_to_currency` works in very familiar fashion, but still echos `$17.00` if there are no cents :(

Comment: Have a try with `to_i`.

Comment: So to clarify, you always want to display the cents as two digits except when it's exactly 0 cent right?

Comment: @rorofromfrance exactly! :)

Comment: @Pavan sorry, I have fixed the format, they are integers already.

Comment: if they're integers already there's no 0.5 to worry about....

Comment: If they are integers,how could the values are `float`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to use the `number_to_currency` then one way you can have what you want work would be:

```
number_to_currency(17.0).chomp(".00") => "$17"
number_to_currency(17.5).chomp(".00") => "$17.50"
```

That way it strips the ending ".00" if present

`chomp(*args)` : "Returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present)." http://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp

Answer (score 1):

You'll be looking for [`strip_insignificant_zeros`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html), like so:

```
number_to_currency("17.00", strip_insignificant_zeros: false) #-> $17.00
number_to_currency("17.00", strip_insignificant_zeros: true) #-> $17
```

Comment: that isn't listed as an option for `number_to_currency`. It is for `number_to_human` and `number_to_percentage` though... does this really work? Also, I believe the asker would want to set it to true, not false - they don't want the .00 in $17.00.

Comment: Yep it works - I just tested in an app we're developing! I think it works because `number_to_currency` invokes one of the other methods which does support the argument. I'll change my answer to reflect the `true` value

Comment: Thanks! But on `17.5` it gives the same `17.5`, instead of `17.50`

Comment: Are you using the scale /precision arg?

Comment: Thanks for heads up - I'll try in a min!